# Can you pass URI parameters in ElasticSearch as part of the search query?

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-2.0, elasticsearch-5

Can parameters like search_type, preference etc. be included in the ElasticSearch query instead of the URI?

Comment: I need to pass `request_shard` in search template too.